# select rows with users' own time range

Tags: mysql

I would like to select rows based on users' own time range.

Suppose I have two tables. The first one is about the user activity log data.

```
| user_id    | date        | activity     |
|:-----------|------------:|:------------:|
| 1          |      1/1/18 |    a1        |
| 1          |     2/12/18 |    a2        |
| 1          |     3/21/18 |    a3        |
| 2          |     1/13/18 |    b1        |
| 2          |      2/4/18 |    b2        |
| 2          |     3/24/18 |    b3        |
```

The second table is the time range I want to extract for each user
user_id, start_date, end_date

```
1, 1/1/18, 3/1/18
2, 2/1/18, 4/1/18
```

The expected result would be
user_id, date, activity

```
1, 1/1/18, a1
1, 2/12/18, a2
2, 2/4/18, b2
2, 3/24/18, b3
```

Comment: I assume the date columns are varchar or char datatypes here.. beter you convert into using date, datetime or time datatypes otherwise to cant compare time ranges correctly or easy

Comment: why `2          |     1/13/18 |    b1  ` is not in result set?

Comment: Store dates as dates and see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need a simple JOIN between both tables with a BETWEEN condition on the activity date :

```
SELECT ua.*
FROM user_activity ua 
INNER JOIN time_range tr 
    ON ua.date BETWEEN tr.start_date AND tr.end_date
```

If your dates are stored as strings (which, as commented by Raymond, seems to be the case), you need to use STR_TO_DATE to convert them :

```
ON STR_TO_DATE(ua.date, '%c/%e/%y') BETWEEN 
    STR_TO_DATE(tr.start_date, '%c/%e/%y')
    AND STR_TO_DATE(tr.end_date, '%c/%e/%y')
```